# Rate equation for the decomposition of hydrogen peroxide with iron(III) chloride as catalyst

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, kinetics, catalysis, rate-equation

I am trying to determine the activation energy of the decomposition of hydrogen peroxide with iron(III) chloride added as a catalyst. To do that, I need to find the rate constant, but I am not sure what to do exactly.

What would the rate equation be in this case for me to be able to calculate this?

Answer (score 0):

You should take steps to measure the volume ${V(t)}$ of the oxygen gas $\ce{O2}$ produced by the decomposition reaction vs. time. Do this up to the time when you consider that this volume will not increase any more. This final volume ${V_∞}$ is proportional to the initial $\ce{H2O2}$ concentration, called $c_o$. Now calculate all differences $\Delta V(t) = V_∞ - V(t)$ for all volume measurements. This $\Delta V(t)$ is proportional to the $\ce{H2O2}$ concentration at time $t$.

Then report the successive values of log$\Delta V(t)$ on the $Oy$ axis, and the time $t$ on $Ox$ axis. The points should be alined, and the slope gives you the first order rate constant $k_1$. Repeat the same measurements at different temperatures. If the points are not well alined, report the inverse $1/V(t)$ vs. the time $t$. If this time the points are alined, the reaction is second order with  a slope equal to the rate constant $k_2$

When these series of measurements are finished, report the log of the different $k_1$ or $k_2$ values vs. ${1/T}$, where $T$ is the absolute temperature in Kelvin. You should obtain a line with a slope equal to $E_a/R$, where $E_a$ is the activation energy of the reaction.